# PHP script with root access?

Tags: php

I need to call a PHP script from a remote computer which will invoke the remote server to change a DNS record.  Is this possible?   I have everything working fine in test environment but PHP doesn't have access to `/var/namdd/mydomain.com.db`.  It's a VPS of mine that I have root access to so getting access isn't a problem.  I just want the script to do it for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: Several possibilities: 1. change the permissions so you don't need `root` access; 2. create a daemon the PHP file can communicate with whose only purpose is to modify that record; 3. create a command that modifies the DNS record and configure `sudo` to allow the PHP user to run that command (and only that command) without a password.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other server is running BIND, the files could be owned by named, not root. Would be a much simpler option. Also, you could make them 777 and then have PHP simply edit them.

Comment: Changing the permissions so PHP can edit them may be a good idea, but 777 is almost never a good idea.

Comment: They are owned my `named`.  I was worried about setting them to 777 thinking it might mess other things up.  Cpanel is normally what edits them.  I will try it and see, worst case I set permissions back to normal.

Comment: I know 777 is never good idea but it's for one domain.  I have a server at home that is going to call a php script and if my home ip changes the PHP script will edit dns and restart named.  My hosted server has the DNS because I want to keep the mail (MX record) on it in case my home server craps out I won't loose email.  Pretty much just a dev setup.  Nothing critical.

Comment: So my mail is hosted on VPS but everything else goes to my home.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways immediately come to mind:

1. Changing the permissions of the file.
2. Creating a daemon to do it.
3. Creating a command and configuring `sudo` to run it without a password.

---

**Changing the permissions of the file**

The simplest case would be to change the permissions of the file. To do this, you'll probably at least want to know

1. the user reading the file, and
2. the user your PHP script runs as.

If the users are the same, then of course the answer is simple: change the owner to that user. Otherwise, if the file contains no sensitive information, you might be able to change the owner to the PHP user and grant read access to all users. Finally, you might be able to create a new group containing those two users and change the group of the file. Then you could change the user of the file to the PHP user and grant write permissions, change the group to the group you created and grant read permissions, and grant no permissions to everyone else.

---

**Creating a daemon to do it**

This is rather involved; I can't say I would recommend this option. Essentially, you have a background process running with whatever privileges are necessary. This process can do whatever needs to be done and communicate with processes of lesser privilege. When the PHP script needs to modify that file, it can send a request over to the daemon, which can then change the file on behalf of the PHP script.

---

**Command with `sudo`**

This is probably one of the best ways to do it. Essentially, you'll need to create some command that does whatever you need to do with the file; then, once you know it works when run as `root` (or preferably some less privileged user which still has the necessary privileges), you can configure `sudo` to let the PHP user execute it as the more privileged user without a password.